# UIRefreshControl is not working in IOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I have implemented UIRefreshControl in my code it works fine in ios 6 and but working in ios 5, any solutions for this, help me

Thanks

Comment: I have found answer in this following link

http://code4app.net/ios/Slime-Refresh/4ff55e116803fa223d000000

Comment: Respected Carl Veazey, Mike Gates, Emil, George Stocker

Please Un Hold my question, so that I may get better solutions for my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `EGOTableViewPullRefresh`. It's awesome "pull down to refresh" feature. It is available on [github](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh). UIRefreshControl is available only in iOS 6.0 and later. `EGOTableViewPullRefresh` can be used in iOS 5 and earlier!

Comment: Thank you Valentin Shamardin

Answer (score 4):

yes, Indeed it is a iOS 6.0 feature.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Meet, but I need Other options to use UIRefreshControl in IOS 5